# error about java.lang.NullExceptionPoint

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I am working on my Project in Netbeans entitled Car reservation system. I've encountered an error in my log in form codes. Once I clicked the login button java.lang.NullExceptionPoint error showed up. 
Any suggestions for my codes? thanks

Here is my code:

```
private void cmdloginMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String sql = txtusername.getText() + "'select * from tblelogin where username='" + "' and userpass='" + txtuserpass.getText() + "'";
        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct");

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid username or password");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have given wrong id to the button. once check the id. Null pointer exception will come when we won't initialize the item or given wrong id.